# Transfering output from GAS(Google App Script) to html

Tags: html

I'll make the succeeding programs which transfers URL defined by GAS to html.
In this time, I set URL as fix letters for simplification, however,
in the actual situations, URL is generated uniquely in every trial.

```js
function getUrl() {
   var url = "https://www.google.co.jp/"
   var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("dialog2").evaluate();

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Download File");
}
// error　ReferenceError: url is not defined　@ test.gs:3
```

html side (dialog2.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
 <body>
    <a href="<?= url ?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Click here</a>
　　<!--↑wanting to get url as a variable letters from the GAS program-->
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm sure that the way of transfering the parameter (this time,url) is the crucial fautor to compile these codes.
If we cannnot get this plan into the practice, please tell me sub plans.
Thank you for checking this question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by defining the paramerter url as property.

correct code (GAS)

```js
function getUrl() {
  var url = "https://www.google.co.jp/"
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("dialog2");
  html.url = url;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate(), "Download File");
}
```